# Using heap sort, append an array elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, heapsort, max-heap

I have given an array `int A[] = {12,10,9,2,11,8,14,3,5};`
In this array, 1st 4 elements(from index 0 to index 3) follow max heap condition. But last 5 elements(index 4 to index 8) don't follow max heap condition. So, I have to write a code so that the whole array follow max heap condition.

I have given a function call `max_heap_append(A,3,8);` and I have to use it in my code to write the program. It is an assignment so I have to follow the instruction.

I have written this code bellow but when I run the program, nothing happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int * a, int * b )
{
    int temp;

    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

}

void heapify( int A[], int q, int i) 
{
    int largest = i;
    int l = 2 * i + 1 ;
    int r = 2 * i + 2;

    if( l < q && A[l] > A[largest])
    {
        largest = l;
    }
    if( r < q && A[r] > A[largest])
    {
        largest = r;
    }
    if( largest != i)
    {
        swap( &A[i] , &A[largest]);
        heapify(A, q, largest);
    }
}



void max_heap_append(int A[], int p , int q) 
{
    int i;

    for( i = q / 2 -1; i >= 0; i--)  
    {
        heapify( A , q , i);
    }
    // sort the heap
    for( i = q; i>= 0; i--)
    {
        swap(&A[0] , &A[i]);

        heapify(A, i, 0);
    }


}
 void printA(int A[], int q)
 {
     int i;
     for( i = 0; i <= q; i++)
     {
         printf("%d", A[i]);

     }
     printf("%d\n");
 }


int main()
{

    int A[] = {12,10,9,2,11,8,14,3};

    max_heap_append(A,3,8);

    printf("Sorted: ");

    printA(A, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not followed heapify from `0 to 3` index.. so u need to heapify all. there is some mistake. if your array size is 8 then u can not excess a[8], you can access `a[0] to a[7]`. so you need to iterate from `0 to 7`.

Try with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int * a, int * b )
{
    int temp;

    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

}

void heapify( int A[], int q, int i)
{
    int largest = i;
    int l = 2 * i + 1 ;
    int r = 2 * i + 2;

    if( l < q && A[l] > A[largest])
    {
        largest = l;
    }
    if( r < q && A[r] > A[largest])
    {
        largest = r;
    }
    if( largest != i)
    {
        swap( &A[i] , &A[largest]);
        heapify(A, q, largest);
    }
}



void max_heap_append(int A[], int p , int q)
{
    int i;

    for( i = q-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        heapify( A , q , i);
    }
    // sort the heap
    for( i = q-1; i>= 0; i--)
    {
        swap(&A[0] , &A[i]);

        heapify(A, i, 0);
    }


}
void printA(int A[], int q)
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main()
{

    int A[] = {12,10,9,2,11,8,14,3};

    max_heap_append(A,3,8);

    printf("Sorted: ");

    printA(A, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's fine, although you're doing more work than necessary. You can start the first loop at `(q-1)/2`, because the items below that are at the leaf level and can't possibly move down.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code

**printA**

One is/can be indicated by the compiler, in *printA* :

> printf("%d\n");

‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument, but there no no argument

It is easy to guess you just wanted to print a newline, so that line can be replaced by

```
putchar('\n');
```

Still in *printA* you print the numbers without a separator, the result is not usable, for instance do

```
printf("%d ", A[i]);
```

When I look at the call of *printA* in *main* the parameter *n* is the number of elements in *A*, so the end test of the *for* is invalid because you try to print a value out of the array, the loop must be :

```
for( i = 0; i < q; i++)
```

**max_heap_append**

in the second *for* the index *i* can value 0, in that case you swap the first element of the array with itself, that has no sense and the same for the call of *heapify* with the 2 last arguments valuing 0

When you call that function in *main* the parameter *q* receive the number of elements in the array, which is also the first value of *i* still in that second *for* and *&A[i]* is out of the array. You need to replace that line by

```
for( i = q-1; i> 0; i--)
```

If I do all these changes :

Compilation and execution :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ gcc -g -Wall h.c
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
Sorted: 2 3 8 9 10 11 12 14 
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```